# Are URL.getRef() and URI.getFragment() the same?

Tags: java, url, uri

Are URL.getRef() and URI.getFragment() the same?

If not, how do they differ?

When running the following test, the results are the same:

```
String url = "http://c.b.a.com:1234/path?p1=1&p2=2#somewhere";
System.out.println(new URL(url).getRef());
System.out.println(new URI(url).getFragment());
```

Output:

```
somewhere
somewhere
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  They are the same thing.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html) for URL says:

> A URL may have appended to it a "fragment", **also known as a "ref" or a "reference"**. The fragment is indicated by the sharp sign character "#" followed by more characters.

Comment: They are not exactly the same.
If you have escaped sequences the URI's getFragment will decode them while URL's getRef won't.

The URL's getRef is same as URI's getRawFragment though.